Самый гибкий способ предоставления печатаемости типу
Например, я разрабатываю свой библиотечный тип A. Как лучше всего предоставить способ его печати, чтобы любой пользователь мог его использовать?
std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream&, const A&);
не всегда удобен, т.к. клиент может не использовать iostream (из-за размеров и перформанса), не все логирующие библиотеки его поддерживают
std::string to_string(const A&); (или метод)
уже выглядит гибче, но при этом динамически выделяет память под строку, что тоже не все клиенты могут позволить
const char* to_string(const A&);
непонятно кто выделяет память
void to_string(char* res, const A&);
вроде бы самый гибкий, но при это out параметр не хочется использовать
Есть ли какие-то практики как лучше всего сделать?

Все это должно быть документировано, и никаких проблем не будет, и ещё имена параметров нормальные задавать, чтобы даже без документации было понятно. Ну и ещё можно добавить какой-то шаблонный метод, для работы с stream.

Самый гибкий на практике способ -- вообще этого не делать. Пусть пользователь библиотеки сам форматирует нужный ему вывод (в т.ч. строки для логирования).

Сейчас std::format набирает популярность. Можно написать std:: formatter для своего типа.

@avp а если у типа есть private поля? Тогда пользователь сам не сможет их вывести HolyBlackCat неплохой вариант, но для новых библиотек; а наверное гибче всего вообще без использования стандартной библиотеки, чтобы всякие урезанные реализации могли юзать тоже

@Андрей, если поле предназначено для логирования, то может и не глубокого смысла делать его private? Вообще, польза от private/protected imho явно преувеличена
